# How to upload a image using Slim Framework

Tags: php, api, slim

I want to storage a image in server and save the path in MySQL, but i'm not finding a good code to do it.

I found this, but does not work:

```
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['upload_directory'] = __DIR__ . '../uploads';


$app->post('/photo', function (Request $request, Response  $response) use ($app) {

$directory = $this->get('upload_directory');

$uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();

$uploadedFile = $uploadedFiles['picture'];
  if($uploadedFile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $filename = moveUploadedFile($directory, $uploadedFile);
    $response->write('uploaded ' . $filename . '<br/>');
 }

 });

function moveUploadedFile($directory, UploadedFile $uploadedFile){
             $extension = pathinfo($uploadedFile->getClientFilename(), 
             PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
             $basename = bin2hex(random_bytes(8));
             $filename = sprintf('%s.%0.8s', $basename, $extension);
             $uploadedFile->moveTo($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);

            return $filename;
            
        }
```

Somebody knows how to upload image and save the path in MySQL?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm a beginner in web service. And I don't know how to store a image in my local server. The code that I tried is in the post above.

Comment: You need a database connection for MySQL. Try this [Slim 4 tutorial](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html).

Comment: Ok, but the file does not storage in local server. The message: <h1>Slim Application Error</h1>
        <p>The application could not run because of the following error:</p>
        <h2>Details</h2>
        <div>
            <strong>Type:</strong> InvalidArgumentException
        </div>
        <div>
            <strong>Message:</strong> Upload target path is not writable
        </div>
        <div>
            <strong>File:</strong> C:\xampp\htdocs\revise\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Http\UploadedFile.php
        </div>
        <div>
            <strong>Line:</strong> 236

Answer (score 0):

First you need a database connection for MySQL. [Read more](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html)

Then create a table, e.g. files(id, path, filename)

To insert the record (after the upload) into the table, you could use an SQL statement as follows:

```php
// ...
$filename = moveUploadedFile($directory, $uploadedFile);
$response->getBody()->write('File uploaded: ' . $filename);

$row = [
    'path' => $directory,
    'filename' => $filename
];
$sql = "INSERT INTO files SET path=:path, filename=:filename;";
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($row);

// ...

return $response;
```

Please note that `$response->write('...')` will not work. It must be `$response->getBody()->write('my content');`.

Edit: Make sure that the `uploads/` directory exists and the directory has write access. For example `chmod -R 1777 uploads/`

Comment: Ok, but the file does not storage in local server. The message shows uo: <h1>Slim Application Error</h1> <p>The application could not run because of the following error:</p> <h2>Details</h2> <div> <strong>Type:</strong> InvalidArgumentException </div> <div> <strong>Message:</strong> Upload target path is not writable </div> <div> <strong>File:</strong> C:\xampp\htdocs\revise\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Http\UploadedFile.php </div> <div> <strong>Line:</strong> 236

Comment: This is something different. Make sure that the `uploads/` directory exists and the directory has write permissions.

Comment: How can I write permissions for 'uploads/'?

Comment: You can google it ;). For example `chmod -R 1777 uploads/` 
 https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-1777/